# Add-Member to Powershell function

Tags: powershell

I want to add a member with source code line number to my object that I can find the function later in the script.
I tried the following:

```
SetProperty("Cmd1") | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Line" -NotePropertyValue $(__LINE__)
```

Comment: Please describe the problem. What doesn't work?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Objects have members. Functions don't.

Comment: The member "Line" wasn't added to the object "Cmd1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it now in this way

```
function __LINE__ { return $MyInvocation.ScriptLineNumber }

$setprop  = $_.SetProperty("cmd") | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "line" -Value $(__LINE__) -PassThru
Write-Host $setprop.Line
```